# Using subprocess in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I was using the subprocess module to run the shell command in python 3. 
Here is my code

```
import subprocess
filename = "somename.py"  # in practical i'm using a real file, this is just for example
subprocess.call("pep8 %s" % filename, shell=True))
```

The output for different files is just `0` or `1`. I am quite new to python 3. Using this in 2.7 gives me the desired output, but here i am not able to figure it out.
This is the output i get in python 2.7 (for a file named - `anu.py` ) -

```
anu.py:2:1: W191 indentation contains tabs
anu.py:3:1: W191 indentation contains tabs
anu.py:3:7: E228 missing whitespace around modulo operator
anu.py:4:1: W191 indentation contains tabs
anu.py:5:1: W191 indentation contains tabs
anu.py:6:1: W191 indentation contains tabs
anu.py:7:1: W191 indentation contains tabs
anu.py:7:9: E231 missing whitespace after ','
anu.py:8:1: W191 indentation contains tabs
anu.py:9:1: W191 indentation contains tabs
1
```

Please help me guys.
Thanks

**Update:**
I tried using `subprocess.check_output` method,
Here is the ouput i got,

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(["pep8", "anu.py"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "X/subprocess.py", line 584, in check_output
it too will be used internally.  Example:
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['pep8', 'anu.py']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`subprocess.call` only returns the exit code of the process it ran. Normally I'd recommend using [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output), which will return the actual output of the subprocess. However, in your particular case, `pep8` will return a non-zero exit code in some cases, which will make `check_output` raise an exception. You can catch the exception and extract the output attribute from it:

```
try:
    output = subprocess.check_output(['pep8', 'anu.py'])
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    output = e.output
```

Or just use `subprocess.Popen` directly:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['pep8', 'anu.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
(output, _) = p.communicate()
```

Note that the `call` behavior hasn't changed between Python 2.x and Python 3.x. The difference in behavior you're seeing might be because you're running Python 2.7 in an interactive prompt, but running the Python 3 version as an actual script. Using `subprocess.call` in the interactive prompt will still end up printing the output of the call, even though it's not actually being returned by the function.

Comment: why are you using this `(output, _)` ??

Comment: `p.communicate()` returns the tuple `(stdoutdata, stderrdata)`. We're only interested in stdout. A common python convention is to use `_` as the variable for tuple arguments we're not actually interested in.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, it works now, after i just had to decode it to 'utf-8'